# How to find the restricted partition of n into k *distincts* parts between a finite set [1;r]?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, euler-maclaurin

It seems to be an opened question.

Indeed, it is easy to find:

- the number of partitions of *n* into *k* **distinct** parts
- the number of partitions of *n* into *k* parts
- the number of partitions of *n* into *k* parts, each of them **less or equal than r** and thus the *k* parts between a finite set [0;r].

However, I have not found any formula for partitions with three restrictions: k parts, k must be distinct, and k must belong to S (S=[1;r]).

To be concrete, what is the number of partition of 60 into 5 distinct parts all of them between [1;50] ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually in your particular example you can remove the "all of them between [1;50]" requirement since any partition of $60$ into $5$ distinct positive parts cannot have a part greater than $50$ (the other four must be at least $1+2+3+4$).  In your particular example, the answer is $2611$.

When Java applets worked on the internet, I would have pointed you at my page http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm which does the calculation by recursion.

The number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct positive parts each no greater than $r$ is same as the number of partitions of $n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ into up to $k$ (not necessarily distinct) positive parts each no greater than $r-k$: you can subtract $1,2,\ldots,k$ from the smallest, second smallest, ..., largest terms respectively.  So in your example the number of partitions of $45$ into up to $5$ positive parts each no greater than $45$ (you see again the point about an unnecessary constraint).

Let's use $f(x,y,z)$ for the number of partitions of $x$ into up to $y$ (not necessarily distinct) positive parts each no greater than $z$.  You start with a lot of zeros but $f(0,0,0)=1$ and then use $$f(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z-1)+f(x-z,y-1,z).$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on that equivalence from distinct to non-distinct partitions please?

Comment: I have added "you can subtract $1,2,…,k$ from the smallest, second smallest, ..., largest terms respectively"

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it, you are transforming the distinct partition into the, um, indistinct case. To me it would be clearer to describe the reverse process, which is (presumably) to add 1, 2, 3 etc to the partitions in ascending order of size.

Comment: Exactly what you add/subtract depends on the question and whether you can.  If your "indistinct case" had an exact number of terms you would instead add $0,1,2,\ldots$. Enjoy the first half of the code at http://www.se16.info/js/PartitionChoice.java which turns $36$ formulations of the question into $13$ recurrences; I suspect fewer is possible.

Comment: OK thanks, I am afraid I don't understand it entirely. Your idea is that the number of partition of 60 into exactly 5 distinct integers taken into [1;50] is the same as the number of partitions of 45 into **up** to 5 (i.e partition with two terms exactly + three terms exactly + four...terms) not specifically distinct term taken into [1;45]. When I compute this with a little code since I know the formulae to get the number of partition with non distinct terms, I finally find 135 751 partitions which far most important than 2611.

Comment: @Eddy: Since there are $89134$ unrestricted partitions of $45$ into any number of positive parts, there will be many fewer restricted partitions of $45$ into up to $5$ positive parts. So $135 751$ is clearly too high

Comment: @Henry: Thanks, alright, my little program apparently computes the number of compositions not the number of partitions. Intuitively to get partitions from compositions one should divide by factorial !. Once I understand, I will finally find a direct formula for distinct partitions taken into a specific set.